# Trying to find files containing an identifier, then move them to a new directory within terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, automator

I'm a beginner with this stuff and seem to be running into an issue.
Basically, I have many files with names containing a keyword (let's call it "Category1") within a directory. For example:

> ABC-Category1-XYZ.txt

I'm trying to move them from a directory into another directory with the same name as the keyword.

I started with this:

```
find /path_A -name "*Category1*" -exec mv {} /path_A/Category1 \;
```

It spit out something like this:

> mv: rename /path_A/Category1 to /path_A/Category1/Category1: Invalid
>   Argument

So I did some fiddling and hypothesized that the problem was caused by the command trying to move the directory Category1 into itself(maybe). I decided to exclude directories from the search so it would only attempt to move files. I came up with this:

```
find /path_A -name "*Category1*" \(! -type d \) -exec mv {} /path_A/Category1 \;
```

This did move the files from their original location to where I wanted them, but it still gave me something like:

> mv: /path_A/Category1/ABC-Category1-XYZ.txt and
>   /path_A/Category1/ABC-Category1-XYZ.txt are identical

I'm no expert, so I could be wrong... but I believe the command is trying to find and move the files from their original directory, then find them again. The directory Category1 is a subdirectory of the starting point, /path_A, So i believe it is finding the files it just moved in the directory Category1 and attempting to move them again.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new files that `find` tries to process. Safest approach is to move them somewhere else not in the `path_A` you are searching with `find`.

Or you can use prune to ignore that directory if you don't have any other directory matching:

```
find /path_A -name '*Category1*' -prune -type f -exec mv {} /path_A/Category1/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although another post has been accepted, let me post a proper answer.
Would you please try:

```
find /path_A -name 'Category1' -prune -o -type f -name '*Category1*' -exec mv -- {} /path_A/Category1/ \;
```

The option `-prune` is rather a command than a condition. It tells `find` to 
ignore the directory tree specified by the conditions *before* `-prune`.
In this case it excludes the directory `Category1` from the search.
The following `-o` is logical `OR` and may be interpreted something like `instead` or `else`. The order of the options makes difference.
Please be noticed the 1st `category1` is the directory name to exclude and the 2nd `*Category1*` is the filenames to find.

If you are not sure which files are the result of `find`, try to execute:

```
find /path_A -name 'Category1' -prune -o -type f -name '*Category1*' -print
```

then tweak the options to see the change of output.